# How to make cuda unavailable in pytorch

Tags: cuda, pytorch

i'm running some code with cudas, and I need to test the same code on CPU to compare running time. To decide between regular pytorch tensor and cuda float tensor, the library I use calls torch.cuda.is_available(). Is there an easy method to make this function return false? I tried changing the Cuda visible devices with

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
```

but torch.cuda.is_available() still return True. I went into pytorch source code, and in my case, torch.cuda.is_avaible returns

```
torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

I assume I should be able to "hide" my GPU at the start of my notebook, so the device count is equal to zero, but i didn't get any success so far. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my code

Instead of trying to trick it, why not rewrite your code? For example,

```
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available() and not os.environ['USE_CPU']
```

Then you can start your program as `python runme.py` to run on GPU if available, and `USE_CPU=1 python3 runme.py` to force CPU execution (or make it semi-permanent by `export USE_CPU=1`).

> I tried changing the Cuda visible devices with

You can also try running your code with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python3 runme.py`; if you're setting the environment variable inside your code, it might be set later than PyTorch initialisation, and have no effect.

Comment: The answer is simple. I'm using a library on top of pytorch. Everytime this library creates a tensor, it does the test i mentionned. So it's way easier for me if I could "trick" pytorch as you say. Furthermore, i only need to run my code once, to compare the time taken on CPU and GPU, so i don't feel like it's worth the investment^^

Comment: Yeah, that's why I quoted "my code" - you didn't mention the check is not, in fact, in your code. See the edit for another possibility.

Comment: I work with jupyterlab, so I did  `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" jupyter lab`, and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You can make `torch.cuda.is_available()` return False by overwriting it. Just run the following code as the first thing in your program:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available = lambda : False
```